# Kotlin PostgreSQL connection Issue

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm brand new to Kotlin and am using the project at https://www.varvet.com/blog/android-qr-code-reader-made-easy/ which is a simple QR Code reader. However, I am trying to connect to a Postgres instance to store the information found in the QR Code. I am using JetBrains "Exposed" (https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) for my SQL transactions. All of the code works, except when I try to connect to the DB, it fails. I've spent more time than I care to admit on this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode
import com.varvet.barcodereadersample.barcode.BarcodeCaptureActivity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SchemaUtils.create
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.*

object Table : IntIdTable() {
val ident: Column<String> = varchar("ident", 500)
}

class tbl(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
companion object : IntEntityClass<tbl>(Table)

var ident by Table.ident
}

/* 
....
....
*/
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == BARCODE_READER_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                if (data != null) {
                    val barcode = data.getParcelableExtra<Barcode>(BarcodeCaptureActivity.BarcodeObject)
                    val p = barcode.cornerPoints
                    mResultTextView.text = barcode.displayValue
                    Database.connect("jdbc:postgresql://IPADDRESS:PORT/DBName", driver = "PostgreSQL", user = "username", password = "password")
                         transaction {
                            create (Table)
                            val neeew = tbl.new {
                                ident = barcode.rawValue
                            }
                        }
                    } else
// REST OF CODE...
```

Comment: can you show us, how exactly it fails? For example error logs

Comment: At a quess, are you missing the permissions for internet access? They are listed here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: Thanks to you both. I was indeed missing the permissions for internet access. I added them and it still failed.

The error is too long to post here. However, here are the important parts from what gather:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=Intent {  launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 }(has extras) }} to activity {com.varvet.barcodereadersample/com.varvet.barcodereadersample.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PostgreSQL

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PostgreSQL

Comment: Also 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "PostgreSQL" on path:

Comment: Is there some sort of Postgres library I'm supposed to install or import that I may not be aware of? That would explain the ClassNotFound

Comment: Looking again at the error, it appears to be a driver name issue. I've tried "PostgreSQL" and "org.postgresql.Driver" and both fail on me. Any idea what it should be?

Comment: 1. Don't use JDBC drivers from Android, you shouldn't connect directly from an Android device to a database, and 2. if you are going to try and do it, you'll at minimum need to have the driver on your classpath (which likely won't work, because the PostgreSQL JDBC driver is developed for normal Java usage, not for Android/Dalvik.